# Within a helper function inside a rake task, how do I access the name of that task?

Tags: rake, rake-task, rakefile

I have a rake task that seeds data for my web application. I have two rake tasks: "production_data" and "demo_data". I also have a function named `create_admin_login`. I would like to put a conditional switch in `create_admin_login` to see which task is calling it and to seed the appropriate email value.

I can't figure out how to know what `:task` is being invoked. How do I do this? (I also realize that this might not be the right way to write a rake file...should I have a separate function called `create_demo_admin_login`? That isn't very DRY.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether it will help querent after all this time, but for others, who'll come in search here.

How to know which task is calling create_admin_login (or in other words - how to know what task is executed/invoked in rake):

```
  def create_admin_login
    foo = Rake.application.top_level_tasks.join(', ')
    if /production_data/ =~ foo
    # or exclude .join(', ') and make if statement with: foo.include?('production_data')
      # seed one data
    else
      # seed other data
    end
  end
```